# End of Life for [lts]?

Tags: discussion, tag-block-request

There is the [lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lts) tag:

> The LTS (Long Term Support) releases that have come out so far include:
>
> - 6.06 Dapper Drake (no longer supported)
> - 8.04 Hardy Heron (no longer supported on desktops; server edition supported until April 2013)
> - 10.04 Lucid Lynx (desktop supported until April 2013, server supported until April 2015)
> - 12.04 Precise Pangolin (desktop and server both supported until April 2017)
>
> ---
>
> Unlike regular releases of Ubuntu, LTS releases can be upgraded directly from one to the 
>   next, without the need to upgrade to all intermediate releases in between.
>
> For example, an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system can be upgraded directly to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. In contrast, an Ubuntu 10.10 system would have to be upgraded to 11.04, and then to 11.10, and then finally to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

This tag wiki is 2 years out of date, doesn't know about Ubuntu 14.04 and seems to have no purpose. The times [lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lts) is used is almost always with an LTS version - mostly 14.04 at the moment. The tag except of [14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04) says "*The current LTS (Long Term Support)*" so tagging with [lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lts) seems really redundant:

[image]

I can't imagine someone being an expert in [lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lts) who wouldn't be watching out for 12.04 or 14.04 questions. It has 7 followers.

Please can this tag be blacklisted?

Comment: +1 I can't think of a legitimate reason for using this tag that wouldn't be covered by something more specific.

Comment: @NathanOsman perhaps to ask about the term itself? As in, "what are LTS releases?". Certainly not in the way the wiki suggests, no.

Comment: @terdon could there ever be more than one question about the term itself (besides "what is it?")? I don't think we can justify keeping a tag like that for a single question.

Comment: @NathanOsman agreed. All I'm saying is that if we were to keep it, the only use would be something like that. Having a "sliding tag" that refers to the current LTS is impossible to maintain.

Comment: It fits for LTS upgrade questions, as the outdated wiki already says.

Comment: Note the tag wiki's been updated since this was posted.  11 hours ago from this post.

Comment: @ByteCommander yes, but is it needed? What value does it add?

Comment: @ThomasW. most likely the edit I made just before posting has been reviewed.

Comment: @Tim I did not say that we should keep it. That's just the only use case I could think of. And it could be covered as well with something like "release-upgrade" or however that tag is called.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's a useless tag.

We should burn it in favor of the more specific tags 12.04, 14.04, etc. I have to agree with @NathanOsman when he says "I can't think of a legitimate reason for using this tag that wouldn't be covered by something more specific."

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only good use for it is any questions related to upgrading to/between/from LTS versions, so perhaps we could blacklist it and create [lts-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lts-upgrade) instead.

Comment: still pretty specific - we could just use upgrade for that?

Comment: True, in fact I'm now realizing there's a greater question potential for [tag:non-lts-upgrade] since the lts upgrades are built to be smooth and easy.